# Does this ul contain an li with a specfic class?

Tags: jquery

In a html page theres a ul which may have an li like this

```
<li class="static selected"><br>
```

I try this to find out if the li exists ...

```
var subList2 = $this.parent().find('span:first .menu-item-text').parent().parent().parent().find('ul');
alert(index + ':' + subList2.has('.static .selected').length);
```

But it doesn't seem to work?
thanks
p

Comment: Read up about XPath, and we can't help you when we don't have enough sample code? We need enough code to be able to debug but if your using parent().parent().parent() I'm sure xpath would be easier.

Comment: Show your html and what does `But it doesn't seem to work?` mean?

Comment: try to use closest()  jquey method instead so many parents. and from this code i'm not getting clear idea what you want to do.

Comment: `$('li.static.selected')` if looking for an element with 2 classes, the selector should have both classes connected. `('.static .selected')` means the `.selected` is a descendant of `.static`.

Comment: $('li [class="staticselected"]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(subList2.find('li.static.selected').length); // check existance
console.log(subList2.find('li').index($('li.static.selected').eq(0))) // find index
```

Comment: thanks that seems like it should work but it is giving 0 everytime. Is there a way to check that this line is actually finding a ul?<br>var subList2 = $this.parent().find('span:first .menu-item-text').parent().parent().parent().find('ul');

Comment: @PeteWhelan You could console.log(subList2) but it would be better if you provided us a bigger part of your code.

Comment: Thanks @Hulothe is there a way to find out which number li the class was found in? ie <ul><li class='a'></li><li class='b'></li><li class='c'></li></ul> then the code would say 1 if I searched for b.

Comment: Yes you could use jQuery [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function. If my answer is convinient for you, please accept it as the good answer [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and vote it up :)

Comment: By doing subList2.index('li.static.selected'); ?

Comment: Not exactly, by doing `subList2.find('li').index($('li.static.selected').eq(0))` (I edited my post).

Comment: subList2.find('li').index($('li.static.selected').eq(0)) gives me -1 even though it should match

Comment: Please edit your original post and include a bigger part of your HTML and JavaScript code so I can help you better. (and don't forget to upvote useful answers :-) )